# The referenced component 'System.Net.Http' could not be found

Tags: .net, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I've created a new project in VS2017 targeting the .NET Framework 4.6.1, and when I add a NuGet package reference to System.Net.Http, I get the following warning for it and all of its depencencies:

`The referenced component 'System.Net.Http' could not be found.`

The project (and its solution) compile but when I run, I get an exception because the assembly can't be found when trying to instantiate an instance of `HttpClient`.

I have confirmed that the `HintPath` is pointing to the correct location in the packages folder and the DLL is there with a size of 193 KB.  I've removed the reference, and tried to add the reference to the DLL directly without success.

I've also tried to add a reference to through Framework > Assemblies, but no matter what I do, the reference has a warning icon, and the properties for the reference look like this:

[image: System.Net.Http Reference Properties]

I've tried the following:

- Remove and add the NuGet reference back
- Remove the reference, clear the NuGet cache, and add the NuGet reference back
- Used `Update-Package -reinstall` with the appropriate arguments
- Copy the solution to another computer and try there (with the same result)

It seems that no matter what I try, I can't get the reference to work.  What other things should I be trying?

Comment: Which template did you use to create the project? What were your steps to create project? This would help others to recreate the problem.

Comment: I used the Azure Service Fabric template; the project that I'm having issues with is a Stateless Service.

Comment: @AdrianAnttila, "when I add a NuGet package reference to System.Net.Http" Is this package custom? If not, what is the package ID, so that we could install this package to reproduce this issue. I have test to installed the package `System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension` which dependence is  `System.Net.Http`. It installed successfully. BTW, can you install any other nuget packages?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT the packages were installed from NuGet.org, and it turns out they weren't the problem; it was a netstandard1_6 reference to another project in the same solution!

Comment: I am getting the same problem but with the following differences: 1) I only get the "The referenced component 'System.Net.Http' could not be found" in the Error List window in Visual Studio 2017 (15.4.2), no runtime error (yet). 2) My 4.6.1 project is referencing .NET Standard 2.0 projects + NETStandard.Library 2.0.0. Any comments on why this is happening appreciated.

Comment: @Marson I'm getting the same warning as you. Have you been able to figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TLDR - Service Fabric services don't work well with project references to .NET Standard packages; instead, use the full .NET Framework for class libraries.

---

After several more hours of trial and error, I was able to determine that the issue was not with the `System.Net.Http` package itself, but was the result of a reference to another project within the solution.

If I referenced the project targeting netstandard1_6, the `System.Net.Http` references (including the dependent packages) would not load or resolve.  Once I removed the project reference, they loaded fine!  Ultimately, I changed my referenced project to a "regular" .NET Framework project, added a reference to that version, and all my references were fine.

There are a few things that we suspect, but aren't sure which was the ultimate cause:

- The project file format for .NET Standard is different than .NET Framework
- Service Fabric projects require x64, and .NET Standard projects target *Any CPU*

Any additional explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Answer (score 4):

Today I ran into this issue. In my case the cause was that I have Dependency Behavior in the NuGet options set to 'Lowest', which downloads the lowest compatible versions of dependent packages. Unfortunately this sometimes means it downloads a package version that is not compatible with your project's runtime version. In my case, package System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extensions caused System.Net.Http version 2.20... to be installed, which was not recognized by my .NET 4.7.1 project.

On the Updates tab in the Nuget Package manager for the solution, it will show updates for these packages. Install them and your problem should be solved.
Alternatively, set the Dependency Behavior to Highest when installing NuGet packages.

Comment: I created a new WebJob project from the template and then updated the packages using NuGet.  NuGet addes several new packages to update which I did.  At that point I saw the assembly not found message.  I deleted everything, recreated the project and this time I set the dependency behavior to highest before performing the update.  This time everything worked as expected and no extra packages were added to the project.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it is useful to delete all existing references.
Then reload the project and every error icon at the references is removed.
Then add every reference manually.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue today when trying to use .net Framework 4.  If you do not have ASP.NET MVC 4 installed, you cannot use `System.Net.Http`.  Install ASP.NET MVC 4 from this [microsoft link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683).  After installing, rebuild and `System.Net.Http` should be available.